# Relaunching the App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I created a tracking app which can run in the background. It is always running in my IPhone. I restart my IPhone. Is there any way that my app also starts automatcially...

Comment: Please don't gift upvotes. What research effort this question shows ?

Comment: actually it was quite helpfull to me. because i wanted to run my app all the times. but with ur answer, i know now, we cant do it...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to start an app automatically after the phone restarts, the user must tap your app icon to launch it.

Comment: "Family Tracker" is an app. if the iPhone is rebooted, It will automatically resume tracking and updating its position!

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/family-tracker/id349880412?mt=8

Comment: There is a way to register your app to significant location changes, that means that if the phone detect that you changed your location it will notify your app and let you process the new location. But this doesn't launch your app! you can't present any UI (except alert view I believe). That is probably what "Family Tracker" is doing...

Answer (score 1):

On restart all the settings of the phone are back to default and the app which once started closes down as soon as you shut your phone off. SO sorry the user will have to tap to start the app.